# ¿como saber que usuario esta logueado con peticiones ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema con mis funciones ajax, hice un login sencillo con una petición get a un servidor REST pidiendo los datos de userName, password y id y lo comparo con los datos ingresados userName y password y si coincide con alguno me redirecciona a la pagina principal que esta en otro html,
en este yo quiero mostrar que usuario esta logueado, su nombre y contraceña, y como al momento de que redirecciona se van todos los datos que consulte asi que hice una variable global del tipo int que inicialize en 0, y en la parte del logueo pase el id a otra función global donde hago el parseo del id y la guardo en mi variable y para ver que si obtenga el valor meti la variable en un console.log y si guarda el valor obtenido el problema recae cuando termina de hacer esto en la validación me redirreciona a mi pagina principal y apesar de que guarde el id en otra funcion global con la variable al momento de cargar la pagina nueva se pierden los datos y nececito poder guardar el id para poder mostrar la informacion del usuario logueado mediante otra peticion ajax pero solo solicitando al usuario con ese id

---

en esta parte hago hago la peticion Get y comparo los resultados con los datos ingresados y obtengo el id de este usuario

```js
function valida() {

        var nombre1 = $("#nombre").val();
        var password1= $("#password").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/Tatiaxca/API/Usuario/",

            success: function(response){                
                console.log("success");

             $.each(response, function(i, value){
                    var nombreA=value.Nombre;
                    var passwordA=value.password;
                    var id=value.IdUsuario;

                    if (passwordA == password1 & nombreA == nombre1) {
                        console.log("usuario encontrado");
                        console.log(id, passwordA, nombreA);
                        idl=parseInt(id);
                        console.log(idl);
                        datoid(idl)
                    location.href="menur.html";


                    }
                    else{
                    notFound();
                }
        }); 
            }

        });
};
```

---

en esta ultima parte mueesto una notificacion, tambien esta la funcion dende verifico que reciba el id en la vaiable y tambien esta la funcioncon la consulta para saber que usuario se logueo pero no recibe nada la variable apesar de que ya le pase el valor.

```js
function notFound() {
                 var $toastContent = $('<span>Registro no encontrado</span>');
                     Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);
            }


           function datoid(a) {
       //         idl=parseInt(a.id);
                console.log(idl)
            }

          function userlog() {  
console.log(idl, "paso");
    var html1='<li id="';
    var htmlid='" style="background-color: black;"><h4 style="color: blue;">'; //aqui recupero los nombre y el id
    var html2='</h4></li>'
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/Tatiaxca/API/Usuario/'+idl, // url del recurso
    type: "GET", // podría ser get, post, put o delete.
    data:{
        IdUsuario:idl
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function(i, value){
            var nombreB=value.nombre;
            console.log(nombreB);
            $("ul.nombre").append(html1+ido+htmlid+"hola :"+nombreB+html2);
 
                
        })  
    }

    });
}
```

---

este es mi codigo en la parte donde esta mi variable global y donde verifico que los campos no este vacios

```js
var idl = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

});

function credenciales(){
        var nombre1 = $("#nombre").val();
        var password1 = $("#password").val();
        userL=nombre1.length;
        passL=password1.length;
        if(userL<1 || passL <1){
            var $toastContent = $('<span>Por favor, ingrese credenciales</span>');
                     Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);
        }
    else{
        valida();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Marco, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tambien lee [ask] y [help] para más info en como hacer preguntas válidas y de calidad .  Un saludo.

Comment: **No** publiques en la sección de respuestas si no es una respuesta. Para añadir informacion, pulsa en [edit]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primero que nada permiteme decirte que la forma en la que estas haciendo el login es insegura, estas haciendo una llamada a la API que te devuelve todos los usuarios con sus respectivas contraseña y haciendo la comprobación en el cliente, cualquiera que se ponga ver tus llamadas en AJAX podría ver todas las credenciales, pero bueno, eso para otra duda.**

En cuanto para mantener el ID del usuario, podrías utilizar el localStorage para mantenerlo en la sesión actual, teniendo un objeto con el id y la duración máxima del logeo.

El código de validación quedaría algo así:

```js
function valida() {

    var nombre1 = $("#nombre").val();
    var password1 = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/Tatiaxca/API/Usuario/",

        success: function (response) {
            console.log("success");

            $.each(response, function (i, value) {
                var nombreA = value.Nombre;
                var passwordA = value.password;
                var id = value.IdUsuario;

                if (passwordA == password1 & nombreA == nombre1) {

                    /// Crear un objeto date y agregarle una hora
                    var today = new Date();
                    today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1);

                    /// objeto con el id usuario y la hora maxima para estar logeado
                    var obj = {
                        id: parseInt(id),
                        maxdate: today
                    }

                    /// Lo guardas en localstorage
                    localStorage.setItem("currentUser",JSON.stringify(obj));

                    console.log("usuario encontrado");
                    console.log(id, passwordA, nombreA);
                    idl = parseInt(id);
                    console.log(idl);
                    datoid(idl)
                    location.href = "menur.html";


                } else {
                    notFound();
                }
            });
        }

    });
};
```

Luego en la carga principal de la aplicación, compruebas si existe el objeto en localStorage y hay dos posibilidades:

- **Si existe** -> Mira la hora, si es menor que la actual, esta logeado y actualizas la hora, si es mayor, se tiene que logear.
- **Si no existe** -> Se tiene que logear.

Espero haberte ayudado.